# Qlikview OCX 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocx, dcom, qlikview

I work on a web application - ASP.NET MVC 4 (C#) the application works with Qlikview OCX, it needs to open the QW client on the server in order to show up some parameters on the UI; the user must log-in using windows authentication, the app impersonates him and then tries to open QW

```
  Client = new QlikView.Application();
  Client.WaitForIdle();
```

Now, on my local machine it works, on the testing server it works but on the production server it doesn't, I get the following in event viewer:

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0E4678AA-415E-11D1-934D-0040333C91CC} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).**

I tried everything I could find on the web... only thing that worked is going into Component Services, to the QW COM and set the Identity to THIS USER (this means qw always runs with the same user, no matter who launches it, and this is not a solution at all).

On my local machine what I did yesterday in order for it to work again (had to do a complete system reinstall, for other reasons), I installed QW, and registered the Qw OCX, then in component services under security tab I gave full permissions to the impersonated user for Launch and activations, Access permissions and Configuration... and then it worked - prior to setting full permissions I got a similar error, but it said clearly: unauthorized. On the server I tried giving permissiosn to everyone... NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE, DefaultAppPool, Everyone, the impersonated user etc... and it's still not working.

If anyone knows anything about this error, especially in the QW context, or can give me some details related to DCOM, impersonated users etc... I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When you say `on my local machine it works`, how does it work, are you using Cassini, IIS Express, IIS?  Are the App Pools the same on both systems.  Are the required dependencies installed?

Comment: Yes, should have given more details.. both running IIS 7, depedencies are installed and the app pools are the same

Comment: I had the same error though in a slightly different situation but this saved me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455448/how-to-connect-to-outlook-2010-while-its-running-in-c